How to fix git repo after replacing directory with submodule
If you replace a subdirectory in a git repo with an identically named submodule, it can break git fetch entirely. Here is a reproducer. In this case the subdirectory contains another submodule which I'm not sure is necessary to reproduce the issue, but it is the situation that caused the bug for us in Gitlab CI, which optionally reuses git directories for unrelated builds.
#!/bin/bash -e

# Create three repos. Leaf_repo is just a plain repo.
mkdir leaf_repo
cd leaf_repo
git init --initial-branch=master
echo "Leaf repo" > README.md
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
cd ..

# Subdir_repo contains leaf_repo as a submodule.
mkdir subdir_repo
cd subdir_repo
git init --initial-branch=master
echo "Subdir repo" > README.md
git -c protocol.file.allow=always submodule add ../leaf_repo
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
cd ..

# Root_repo initially contains `subdir_repo` as a *directory*, not a submodule
# and `leaf_repo` under that directly as a submodule.
mkdir root_repo
cd root_repo
git init --initial-branch=master
echo "Test" > README.md
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
mkdir subdir_repo
git -c protocol.file.allow=always submodule add ../leaf_repo subdir_repo/leaf_repo
git add .
git commit -m "Add leaf repo"

# Now imagine someone creates an MR on a branch that switches the `subdir_repo`
# to be a submodule instead of a normal directory.
git switch -c an_mr
git rm subdir_repo/leaf_repo
git commit -m "Remove leaf_repo submodule"
rmdir subdir_repo
rm -rf .git/modules # Otherwise you get "fatal: not a git repository: '.git/modules/subdir_repo'; fatal: A git directory for 'subdir_repo' is found locally with remote(s):"
git -c protocol.file.allow=always submodule add ../subdir_repo
git commit -m "Convert subdir_repo to submodule"

# Now someone else reuses this repo (with git strategy FETCH) but they
# are on `master` again.

echo "--- Fetch attempt 1 ---"

(
    git checkout -f -q master
    git submodule init
    git submodule sync --recursive
    git submodule foreach git clean -ffdx
    git submodule foreach git reset --hard
    git submodule update --init --recursive
) || true

# The fetch above will fail with errors, so we do try and clean the repo.
echo "--- Clean worktree ---"

git rm -rf --ignore-unmatch .
git clean -ffdx

# However this will still fail.
echo "--- Fetch attempt 2 ---"

git checkout -f -q master
git submodule init
git submodule sync --recursive
git submodule foreach git clean -ffdx
git submodule foreach git reset --hard
git submodule update --init --recursive

echo "SUCCESS" # Not printed.

This gives this error:
Synchronizing submodule url for 'subdir_repo/leaf_repo'
error: submodule git dir '/path/to/root_repo/.git/modules/subdir_repo/leaf_repo' is inside git dir '/path/to/root_repo/.git/modules/subdir_repo'
fatal: refusing to create/use '/path/to/root_repo/.git/modules/subdir_repo/leaf_repo' in another submodule's git dir

The "clean worktree" step is something I added to gitlab CI a while back to avoid issues like this. I wanted to just rm -rf the whole repo on git fetch failure and start again (classic Git style!), but the Gitlab employees were concerned about that wiping out large cached files from .git. At the time the git rm -rf ... git clean -ffdx were enough to fix the other issue I identified that could break git fetch, but I didn't have a reproducer for this one.
So the question is: once a Git repo is broken like this, can you find a command that will fix it without requiring a full refetch?
More specifically, I want a generic command that could be implemented in gitlab-runner.

I think the best solution in your specific case is to use git submodule deinit to remove the existing submodule structure from subdir_repo before git fetch

Can you give me some commands that would fix this without creating a new commit and without using any submodule names? The point is to fix it in a generic manner so gitlab-runner can do it.

I tried git submodule deinit --force --all. Doesn't work. You get error: could not lock config file... and warning: could not look up configuration 'remote.origin.url'..

This is already interesting, The error messages you're getting point to a potential issue with your Git configuration or permissions

There's no issue with my Git configuration or permissions. This is a bug in Git.

I possibly don't understand what you're trying to achieve, especially by generic command that could be implemented in gitlab-runner. But, have you tried doing a reset with reflog? I was able to get the repo in working condition locally with the same

The script I posted is a recreation of what can happen in Gitlab CI. The Clean worktree is something that Gitlab does automatically. I want to modify the commands there so it can also clean up this mess. It can't be manually looking in reflog or running commands on specific submodules. It needs to be commands that fix the repo no matter what the history is or which submodules exist. Something like git submodule deinit --force --all (except that doesn't work).

What commands did you run to get it working anyway? If you can modify the script by only adding commands to the Clean worktree section, that makes it work then that sounds like a solution!
